# Smart Pointers, this, and Constructors

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

> **Synoposis:** convert the raw pointers in the first block of code below to smart pointers while leaving the rest of the functionality as
>   unchanged as possible.

---

I was writing some code in which I'm trying to pass a pointer into an object's constructor, with the goal of making this pointer point to the constructed object by the time the constructor returns.

(Note: this originated in a much more complicated situation, but I've simplified it to the essence of the problem.  Thus, if you try to ask *why* I'm doing this, you won't necessarily find a sensible answer in this context - but that's not the point of the question.)

After struggling with the smart-pointer implementation, I reverted to raw pointers to ensure I wasn't missing a fundamental problem:

```
#include <iostream>

class Thing {
 public: 
  Thing(int data, Thing* thing_ptr) {
    data_ = data;
    *thing_ptr = *this;
  }

  void PrintData() {
    std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  int data_;
};

int main() {
  Thing* thing_ptr;
  Thing t(6, thing_ptr);
  thing_ptr->PrintData();

  return 0;
}
```

That went without a hitch, but when I returned to smart pointers, I couldn't seem to reproduce this functionality.  The basic problem is that I don't know how to initialize the smart pointer without either doing unnecessary extra work or not behaving correctly.

The first thing I tried was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Thing {
 public: 
  Thing(int data, std::unique_ptr<Thing>& thing_ptr) {
    data_ = data;
    thing_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Thing>(this);
  }

  void PrintData() {
    std::cout << data_ << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  int data_;
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing_ptr;
  Thing th(6, thing_ptr);
  thing_ptr->PrintData();

  return 0;
}
```

which I suppose fails (core dump at runtime) because **`this`** is not really a pointer to `Thing`, but rather a pointer to an uninitialized block of memory with the right size to hold a `Thing`.  Actually I'm not 100% sure what's happening here, but since this failed with both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, I decided I should first initialize the smart pointer, and then assign **`this`** to its contents.

The problem is that I can't get around creating an extra object with this method (which in turns requires even adding an additional constructor).

```
  Thing() : data_(0) {}

  Thing(int data, std::unique_ptr<Thing>& thing_ptr) {
    data_ = data;
    if (!thing_ptr) {
      thing_ptr = std::make_unique<Thing>();
    }
    *thing_ptr = *this;
  }
```

Here I make a `Thing::Thing()` only to assign it away the very next line, which is certainly not the correct approach.

Could someone <s>smart</s> point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not the problem but the first code block should be `Thing(int data, Thing*& thing_ptr) {
    data_ = data;
    thing_ptr = this;
  }` otherwise you have undefined behavior.

Comment: `Thing th(6, thing_ptr);` what happens if `th` goes out of scope. Also what happens if the smart pointer tries to delete the object on the stack.

Comment: Well, I think that's why I put the `thing_ptr` in the same scope as `th`.  But it does seem that this approach might be opening the door for a lot of problems.  Maybe the right way is just to assign the pointer after construction?

Comment: *`this` is not really a pointer to `Thing`, but rather a pointer to an uninitialized block of memory with the right size to hold a `Thing*`* It's an initialized block of memory. C++ requires all objects to be initialized before entering the body of a constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver Can you quickly explain why?  I thought I can do something like `void foo(int* p) { *p = 5 }` and then later `int x = 7; foo(&x)` yielding the value 5 to be assigned to x.  Is this different?

Comment: When you do `Thing* thing_ptr;
  Thing t(6, thing_ptr);` `thing_ptr` doesn't actually point to anything.  doing `*thing_ptr = *this;` then dereferences a pointer to "nothing" and assigns an object to it but you are not allowed to do that.  There is no object at where the pointer points.

Comment: Smart pointers own the objects they refer to. Trying to make a smart pointer refer to an object that already exists defeats the whole purpose of the **smart** part of the pointer. This is what raw pointers are for. (possibly weak pointer, bu then the original object need to already be a `std::shared_ptr`).

Comment: The second example attempts to hand over ownership of `*this` to `thing_ptr`, but you're not allowed to do that. (The object will be destroyed twice, which has undefined behaviour.) Transfer of ownership is not something an object itself can decide, only its rightful owner can.

Comment: Since your "non-smart" version assumes that it's given a valid pointer (it has undefined behaviour otherwise, such as in your example use), why wouldn't the "smart" version assume the same?

Answer (score 3):

The most common use of smart pointers is to manage the lifetime of an object.  But note that when you declare a variable with class type, as in

```
Thing th(6, thing_ptr);
```

you have no choice about the lifetime of that object: it will end at the next enclosing `}` if declared in a function block, or with the end of the lifetime of the containing object if declared as a class member, or at the end of the program if declared as a namespace member.  `std::unique_ptr<T>` using the default deleter can only contain a pointer to an object that was created using `new`, since the default deleter attempts to use `delete`.

If your pointers will always be to objects with ordinary declarations like this, and not created with using `new`, then you're stuck making sure on your own that the pointers are only used during the lifetime of the objects they pointed at.  And in that case, there's not much advantage to be gained from using `std::unique_ptr`; you can go ahead and use a raw pointer, which is still the ordinary way to represent a pointer when something else (here the C++ language itself) is responsible for lifetime issues.

If you want the possibility of pointers that outlive the function block where the object is created, you can't use the ordinary object declaration syntax.  One possible alternative would be to require all object creation to use a `create` function rather than directly declaring an object:

```
class Thing {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Thing> create(const Thing& src)
    { return { new Thing(src) }; }
    static std::unique_ptr<Thing> create(int data)
    { return { new Thing(data) }; }

    void PrintData() const;

private:
    // All constructors private, to make sure a Thing can ONLY be
    // created by a create() function - including the copy constructor.
    Thing(const Thing&) = default;
    explicit Thing(int data) : data_(data) {}

    int data_;
};

int main() {
    auto thing_ptr = Thing::create(6);
    thing_ptr->PrintData();
}
```

Comment: This is cool, I didn't know it is allowed to make constructors private.